# How do I select a single row in Magento in a custom database for display in a block?

Tags: magento

I don't want to use `foreach` to loop through an array of multiple rows, as I am planning on only displaying only *one* row and using a variable. I can't find information for this online.

What doesn't work

```
    $param = $this->getRequest()->getParam('manufacturer');
    $extrabrand = Mage::getModel('brands/brands')->getCollection();
    $extrabrand->addFieldToFilter('attributelabelid', $param);
    //$extrabrand->setAttributelabelid($param);
    $extrabrand->load();
```

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Desbest_Brands_Model_Mysql4_Brands_Collection::getDescription() in
>   /home/desbest/public_html/clients/magentofull/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/Desbest_Brands/brand_info.phtml
>   on line 20

Plus there is no EAV.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without seeing the code in `brand_info.phtml` it's hard to say what the problem is, but my guess is you're using the collection in `$extrabrand` as though it were a model.  Try this instead

```
//get the parameter from the request
$param = $this->getRequest()->getParam('manufacturer');

//instantiate the brand/brand model, and use 
//its `getCollection` method to return a collection
//object
$collection = Mage::getModel('brands/brands')->getCollection();

//add the paramater as a filter
$collection->addFieldToFilter('attributelabelid', $param);

//get the first item of the collection (load will be called automatically)
$extrabrand = $collection->getFirstItem();

//look at the data in the first item
var_dump($extrabrand->getData());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get only 1 element (first) from the collection, use `current()` function:

```
$param = $this->getRequest()->getParam('manufacturer');
$extrabrandCollection = Mage::getModel('brands/brands')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('attributelabelid', $param);

$extrabrand = current($extrabrandCollection->getItems());
```